# Configuring vim installed via NixOS's home-manager

Tags: package-management, vim, nixos

I'm just getting started with NixOS, and I'm trying to us `home-manager` to declaratively control which packages I have installed and deploy their configurations to my home directory.

I told `home-manager` to install `vim_configurable`

```
# ~/.config/nixpkgs/home.nix
{ config, pkgs, ... }:
{
  home.packages = [
    pkgs.vim_configurable
    #...
  ]
  #...
```

Which worked fine, but I ran into errors when I tried to [use `program.vim` to configure it](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Vim):

```
  #...
  programs.vim = {
    enable = true;
    settings = {
      expandtab = true;
      tabstop = 2;
    };
  };
```

Running `home-manager switch` gave me an error due to conflicting versions of `gvimdiff`

```
; home-manager switch
these 3 derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/z8imrylbxzmk161gc1jjj2nsjdaiv0ca-home-manager-path.drv
  /nix/store/2wwz04y7yqrzizicc160n630a6kja778-activation-script.drv
  /nix/store/pyx34c22lz2f6nw2pdjgddsg8sy5wz0c-home-manager-generation.drv
building '/nix/store/z8imrylbxzmk161gc1jjj2nsjdaiv0ca-home-manager-path.drv'...
error: collision between `/nix/store/vvb9a43fpmsijx42k3jvrr1a8l6jq6da-vim_configurable-8.2.5172/bin/gvimdiff' and `/nix/store/xyhfc9g3qk3i42gqmp05r0lsab7nng14-vim/bin/gvimdiff'
error: builder for '/nix/store/z8imrylbxzmk161gc1jjj2nsjdaiv0ca-home-manager-path.drv' failed with exit code 25;
       last 1 log lines:
       > error: collision between `/nix/store/vvb9a43fpmsijx42k3jvrr1a8l6jq6da-vim_configurable-8.2.5172/bin/gvimdiff' and `/nix/store/xyhfc9g3qk3i42gqmp05r0lsab7nng14-vim/bin/gvimdiff'
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/z8imrylbxzmk161gc1jjj2nsjdaiv0ca-home-manager-path.drv'.
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/pyx34c22lz2f6nw2pdjgddsg8sy5wz0c-home-manager-generation.drv' failed to build
```

I'm guessing this is because `programs.vim.enable = true` instructs `home-manager` to add the system vim, or something, and that's conflicting?

Removing `enable = true` got rid of the error, but none of the configuration settings seemed to come through, which made specifying the `programs.vim` block at all rather pointless.

Am I doing something wrong? Should this work, or does this sort of configuration expect me to have installed packages by updating `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to choose an approach: either you install vim/vim_configurable yourself or you let home manager do it for you.